# SQL to find data that exists in some tables and doesn't exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server,
I want to select data that exists in the tables A,C,D and don't exist in B. Can I write like below?

```
Select A.Store,C.Item,D.Cost 
from A 
  Inner Join C on A.Store=C.Store and A.Item=C.Item
  Inner join D on C.Store=D.Store and C.Item=D.Item
     And Not exists (Select * from B where A.Store=B.Store and A.Item=B.Item)`
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your query???  It seems like the correct one.

Comment: Sometimes I write queries that creates lot of performance issues. Just checking to see If this is the best way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your query completely makes sense.

You can also use the `left join` as follows:

```
Select A.Store,C.Item,D.Cost 
from A 
  Inner Join C on A.Store=C.Store and A.Item=C.Item
  Inner join D on C.Store=D.Store and C.Item=D.Item
  Left join B on A.Store=B.Store and A.Item=B.Item
 Where b.store is null;
```